# can't get $q.all work on multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I really struggle with that... I have a function in my controller generating a certain amount of promises, passed to another function which also generate promises...

```
angular.forEach($scope.items,function(value,key) {
   myService.getPage(item).then(function(data) {
      myFunction(data)
   });

function myFunction(singlePage) {
   myService.getPage(singlePage.next).then(function(data) {
     myFunction(data)
   });
}
```

What i want to achieve is to somehow know when all promises will be resolved

I tried to wrap my promises in an array and pass it to $q.all in all kind of configuration but without success..Any kind of help would be really cool !! Thanks

Comment: You're in an infinite loop by recursively calling myFunction from within myFunction, but never giving a condition on when to NOT call myFunction.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need "return" in your handlers. And, right, I haven't spotted recursion.

Comment: can you show us the attempt with the `$q.all()` method, cause that seems the right approach imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the infinite recursion loop you've created, let's do this...

```
var allPromises = [];
angular.forEach($scope.items,function(value,key) {
    allPromises.push(myService.getPage(value));
});

$q.all(allPromises)
    .then(function (arrayOfResults) {
        // do something
    });
```

One thing to note, you are passing in value and key, but using "item".  You need to be using value.

Comment: Well, of course there is a condition for the function to stop. I just tried to post the shortest code. thanks for your answer !